# How to view content in right eye from Unity + Oculus Rift from primary monitor

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

Completely new to Unity Here. I'm using Unity 5.3.4f1 to make a VR Game on Oculus Rift.

Currently I'm using the setting under the OVRCameraRig to target display to be right eye only.

This is the setting for the Camera

[image]

In order to monitor what the player is doing, I would like to display his right eye on the primary monitor. However, for some weird reason the content rendered on the primary monitor is the one from his left eye which is blacked out.

Could someone help me with figuring out how to do so?

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference, but anyways you should fix you camera's viewport rect. you set its width and height to be 3, making it a 3x3 rect, the viewport rect is of size 1x1. maybe thats why your camera is not rendered correctly

Comment: You might be better off asking on the [Oculus Developer forum in the Unity section](https://forums.oculus.com/developer/categories/unity)

Comment: @xyLe_ Edited it but it doesn't help. The primary monitor(the one on the PC) is still displaying the blacked out left eye instead of the right. Thanks for pointing it out though.